# Нужно ли обновлять браузер до последней версии?

Tags: безопасность, браузер

Добрый день или вечер. Где я могу посмотреть какие уязвимости имеет та или иная версия браузера ? Нужно ли обновлять браузер до последней версии для защиты, если я уже использую расширения Ublock, NoScript, https everywhere, отключен WebRTC + меняю user agent.

Comment: ...и все это не поможет вам защитить ваши данные от перехвата,  если вы полезете своим старым браузером на старый сервер по старому ssl...

Comment: Не понимаю, для чего может понадобиться его не обновлять.

Answer (score 1):

Для чего может понадобиться старая версия браузера?

- **Для проверки совместимости вашего сайта со всеми версиями браузеров**.
  Для этого проще иметь несколько виртуалок, как делают тестеры, нежели
  подвергать опасности свою основную систему. К тому же, у большинства пользователей браузеры всё-таки обновляются.
- **Если стоит дополнение, которое не будет работать с новой версией**. На мой взгляд, всё равно не стоит, проще найти похожее дополнение.
  Например, моё любимое QuickDrag я успешно заменил на FireDrag.
- **Любимая казуальная игрушка не идёт в новом браузере**. Да, многие флэш-игры просто перестали запускаться в новых версиях Firefox и
  Seamonkey. Но ради игрушки подвергать опасности свой компьютер? У
  меня для детских игр выделен отдельный компьютер, они его и мучают.
  Раз в несколько месяцев тупо восстанавливаю систему из отключаемого
  зеркала.
- **Какое-то действительно нужное приложение не работает с новым браузером**. Знаю, что у наших бухгалтеров какие-то модули для аукционов отказываются работать с новыми версиями, пока поддержка не обновит модули. Ну, вот, пожалуй, единственный момент, когда можно не обновлять браузер, но необходимо тщательно следить за происходящим и обязательно обновиться, как только предоставится такая возможность.

Поэтому лучше обновиться - вы уменьшите вероятность подцепить какую-то гадость и того, что какой-то ресурс будет отображаться неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

Чем новее браузер тем меньше уязвимостей.
Поясню. Дело в том что в старых браузерах

1. Много багов
2. Не поодерживается весь современный HTML, JavaScript, CSS итп.
3. Есть уязвимости

Конечно в новой версии уязвимости могут появиться новые, но они скорее всего неизвестны пока хакерам, или мало кому известны, как создатели браузера узнают про уязвимость, они её устраняют.

А вот в старых браузерах уязвимости хорошо известны и могут быть использованы против вас.

PS: Используя старый браузер вы создаёте головную боль разработчикам, так как им приходится в коде сайта поддерживать старую функциональность. Лично я в своём коде вообще не делаю поддержку старых браузеров, знаю что так не только я делаю. Так что используя старый браузер некоторые сайты у вас вообще могут не работать.